# Retrieving a variable from ahref or onclick load to the same page

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to pass a variable using onclick or a `href` and load that variable to the same page to do further manipulation. Below is my code.

```
<form id= "frm1" action="index.jsp" method="post"/>
<c:forEach items="${mybean.flag}" var="element">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="sub(${element.CASE});return false;">${element.CASE}</a>
```

Appreciate your time in advance.

Thanks

Comment: what is the Error you are getting?

Comment: I don't see any errors. I cannot retrieve the variable.

Comment: I am agree with Ravi's answer, please try once

Answer (score 1):

Missing quotes.

```
onclick="sub('${element.CASE}');return false;"
```

Comment: I was trying 2 different options. Option 1. Load on the same page and do further processing with onclick or ahref. Option 2. Send the variable as a parameter to javascript function and use ajax to do further processing.

Comment: BTW.. Above suggestion doesn't solve my problem. How can I send a variable to the same page using either a href or onclick?

Comment: Is your <a> tag getting generated correctly? Do you get any value for ${element.CASE} as your link text? If not problem is with your JSP not javascript (except for the quotes I've already pointed).

Comment: I am seeing the output value for ${element.CASE}. So its not the jsp.

Comment: Can you view > source and post the relevant html code that's generated by the jsp?